# VideoPlayer API 19 not displaying video

Tags: android, android-fragments, video, android-4.4-kitkat

I am trying to play a video using the videoPlayer on KitKat but when I play the video, all I hear is the audio and see is a blank screen.

```
<VideoView android:id="@+id/videoView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

String path = "android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + 
R.raw.mainmenu;

videoView.setMediaController(new 
android.widget.MediaController(getContext()));
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));

videoView.requestFocus();
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    // Close the progress bar and play the video
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
    }
});
```

My video is a .mp4 built using H.265 encoding.
When I tried using a video made in H.264 encoding I kept getting the error "Can't play this video" showing on the emulator.

The emulator was running api version 19 (KitKat).

Edit: Online videos work fine, but it seems the second I try to use a local file it doesn't play.

Comment: Have you tried on a real device - emulators and video can create some confusing issues (do a quick search for emulator video problems)?